# Javascript Nested Loop Pushing to Array

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am relatively new to programming and am having some issues with a project I am working on.

```
msg.newCG2 = [];
for(i=0;i<msg.newCG.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<msg.campaignGroup.length;i++){
        if(msg.campaignGroup[j].col10 === msg.newCG[j]){
            msg.groupTotals = msg.groupTotals + msg.campaignGroup[j].col11;
    }
    msg.newCG2.push(msg.newCG[i], msg.groupTotals)
    }
}
```

Basically, for each one of the "IDs" (integers) in msg.newCG, I want to look for each ID in msg.campaignGroup and sum up the totals for all listings with the same ID, from msg.campaignGroup.col11 - then push the ID and the totals to a new array - msg.newCG2.

When I run the code, the first item sent through processes, but grinds to a halt because of memory. I assume this is because of an error in my code.

Where did this code go wrong? I am sure that there are better ways to do this as a whole, but I am curious where I went wrong.

Comment: Looks like you are pushing every message to the array regardless of if the condition is true. The condition just sets a variable. Additionally, that push is inside both loops.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you happen to have any time to correct this code so I can see where I went wrong with my logic?

Comment: How big are the original arrays?

Comment: 300 entries in one and about 4000 in the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your second for loop and the push needs to happen inside the outer loop.

```
msg.newCG2 = [];
for(i=0;i<msg.newCG.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<msg.campaignGroup.length;j++){
        if(msg.campaignGroup[j].col10 === msg.newCG[i]){
            msg.groupTotals = msg.groupTotals + msg.campaignGroup[j].col11;
        }
    }
    msg.newCG2.push(msg.newCG[i], msg.groupTotals)

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the typo but it still getting the memory issues!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
msg.newCG2 = [];

for (i=0; i < msg.newCG.length; i++) {

    var groupTotal = 0;

    for (j=0; j < msg.campaignGroup.length; j++) {
        if (msg.campaignGroup[j].col10 === msg.newCG[i]){
            groupTotal = groupTotal + msg.campaignGroup[j].col11
        }
    }

    msg.newCG2.push(groupTotal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping 1.2M times, it would be more efficient to use a single-pass over the 4000 campaign groups, grouping by id to create an array of totals for all ids -- I like using the `reduce()` function for this:

```
var cgMap = msg.campaignGroups.reduce(function(arr, grp) {
        var grpid = grp.col10;
        var count = grp.col11;
        var total = arr[grpid] || 0;
        arr[grpid] = total + count;
    },
[]);
```

I know, the reduce(...) function is not the easiest to grok, but it takes the second arg (the empty array) and passes it, along with each campaign group object in turn, to that inline function. The result should be a simple array of group totals (from `col11`), indexed by the group id (from `col10`).

Now, it's just a matter of returning the totals for those 300 ids found in `msg.newCG` -- and this `map()` function does that for us:

```
var cgOut = msg.newCG.map(function(gid) {
        return cgMap[gid];  // lookup the total by group id
    }
);
```

I've made some assumptions here, like the group ids are not terribly large integers, and are rather closely spaced (not too sparse). From the original code, I was not able to determine the format of the data you are wanting to return in `msg.newCG2`. The final `push()` function would append 2 integers onto the array -- the output group id and the total for that group. Having pairs of group ids and totals interleaved in a flat array is not a very useful data structure. Perhaps you meant to place the total value into an array, indexed by the group id? If so, you could re-write that line as:
`msg.newCG2[msg.newCG[i]] = msg.groupTotals;`